# Why does macOS specific terminal shortcuts like Left-arrow + Option work in a remote shell on Ubuntu with a dedicated pty?

Tags: bash, tty, pty

Why do macOS specific terminal shortcuts like Left-arrow + Option work in a remote shell on Ubuntu with a dedicated pty?

I'm trying to understand why macOS specific terminal shortcuts like `Left-arrow + Option` for moving one word to the left in Bash work in a remote shell on Ubuntu.

The `tty` output in the remote shell:

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/0
```

Normally, Ubuntu expects `ALT + b` for moving one word to the left in Bash.

Does it work, because there is a local pty that maps `Left-arrow + Option` to something generic that the remote pty understands? If so, how can I see the name of the local pty?

Comment: What are the contents of `~/.inputrc` on the remote Ubuntu system? Also, if these are options you've set in your graphical terminal emulator, then I guess it's the terminal emulator that's doing the translation anyway. Both on your local machine and on the remote.

Comment: @terdon - `~/.inputrc` doesn't exist on the remote system. Can you confirm my assumption that there are two terminals in play, namely the local and the remote ones? If so, how can I see the name of the local one, while in the remote shell?

Comment: I think it's just your GUI that's doing it. Try connecting to the remote using a different terminal emulator. `xterm` for instance. I expect the shortcuts won't work.

Comment: GUI? Don't you mean local terminal?

Comment: Yes, I mean whatever graphical application you are using as a terminal emulator. I believe the default on macOS is iTerm? Try using another one and see if the shortcuts work. I expect these shortcuts you're talking about are handled by whatever terminal app you are using.